# Java 8 - Wildcard extends with BiPredicate not working

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have no idea why it's not working.

**Error message in eclipse:** 
The method test(Fruit, capture#1-of ? extends Fruit) in the type BiPredicate is not applicable for the arguments (Fruit, Mango)

```
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

public class PredTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Fruit {
            public String name;
            public String color;
            Fruit(String name) {this.name = name; }
        };

        class Apple extends Fruit {
            Apple() {super("Apple");}
        };
        class Mango extends Fruit {
            Mango() {super("Mango");}
        };

        BiPredicate<Fruit, ? extends Fruit> tester = (f, nf) -> {
            System.out.println(nf.name);
            return true;
        };
        Fruit f = new Fruit("Not named");
        Apple a = new Apple();
        Mango m = new Mango();

// ########### I see error in the below line
        System.out.println(tester.test(f, m));

    }

}
```

Comment: You should use `? super Fruit` instead. [What is the difference between <? super T> and <? extends T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: `PECS` strikes again...

Comment: @BackSlash or indeed just `BiPredicate<Fruit, Fruit>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you changed your lambda expression to:

```
    BiPredicate<Fruit, ? extends Fruit> tester = (Fruit f, Apple nf) -> {
        System.out.println(nf.name);
        return true;
    };
```

Would you still expect the compiler to allow passing a `Mango` to this `BiPredicate`?

Based on the compile time type - `BiPredicate<Fruit, ? extends Fruit>` - of `tester`, the compiler doesn't know if `Mango` is allowed, so it doesn't allow it.

Changing your `BiPredicate` to:

```
BiPredicate<Fruit, ? super Fruit> tester = (f, nf) -> {
    System.out.println(nf.name);
    return true;
};
```

will eliminate the compilation error.

Comment: But how can it then access `nf.name`, if `nf` could be any superclass of `Fruit` (eg `Object`)?

Comment: @daniu `BiPredicate<Fruit, ? super Fruit>` could be assigned a `BiPredicate<Fruit, Fruit>`, so you can't pass an `Object` to `tester.test()`.

Comment: But `BiPredicate<Fruit, ? super Fruit>` could also be assigned a `BiPredicate<Fruit, Object>`, no?

Comment: @daniu yes, but then the lambda expression won't contain `nf.name`. And anyway, the compiler can't allow you to pass `Object` as the second parameter of the BiPredicate's method, since your code must be type safe for any possible assignment to the `BiPredicate<Fruit, ? super Fruit>` variable.